# Subdivide and re-weight parallel/sibling bones? (or, how to deform-rig lips)

Tags: vertex-weights

I have several lip bones, as shown. They are not linked to each other in a chain, but share a parent and grandparent (maxilla and head).

[image]

Each non-corner lip bone is weighted generally like this along the length of the lip:

[image]

I would like to have more than 3 bones per lip between the lip-corner bones for finer control of the mouth polys (e.g. 4 or 6). **Is it possible to subdivide parallel/sibling bones and redistribute weights between them? Alternatively, can someone point me to an effective way to rig lips (not Rigify plugin because I don't know how to export that)?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select the armature, in edit mode use shift D to duplicate some lips bones, place them where you want them (the duplicated will have the same parent-child relationships), then in pose mode select all lips bones, go to object mode, shift select the mesh, go to weight paint mode and use the weights menu "Automatic assign from (selected) bones".

Make some manual weight adjustments if  needed.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that in a sec. Just wondering, this Vimeo https://vimeo.com/18878572 has the lips bones all linked to each other following the contour of the lip (at ~19:47)--are there certain advantages to this setup? I wonder if it allows for an IK rig, e.g. moving the middle lips bone(s) causes the rest on the same lip to also move. (Maybe the same would also be helpful in the eyes?)

Comment: Check this serie on rigging, with examples of many different ways of rigging an eye, so you can choose which one you prefer for your model. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7rk-zFvVis